# Palatini Formalism into the Einstein-Hilbert action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, action

I'm trying to work out the Palatini approach into the Einstein-Hilbert action. I'm reading this from Ray D'Inverno book. Varying the action w.r.t. the symmetric connection yields this equation:
$$\frac{1}{2}\delta^b_c\nabla_d (\sqrt{-g}g^{ad})+\frac{1}{2} \delta^a_c\nabla_d (\sqrt{-g}g^{bd})-\nabla_c (\sqrt{-g}g^{ab})=0\tag{1}$$ 
And it's written from here that we can prove:

$i)\nabla_c (\sqrt{-g}g^{ab})=0$

$ii)\nabla_c \sqrt{-g}=0$

$iii)\nabla_c g^{ab}=0$

$iv)\nabla_cg_{ab}=0$

How can this be proved? This is a vital important result as it proves that we end up with the  metric connection.

Comment: Start by contracting $b$ and $c$.

Comment: @mmeent Yea that gets $\nabla_c (\sqrt{-g}g^{ac})=0$. How can we get from this $\nabla_c \sqrt{-g}g^{ab}=0$ and the rest?

Comment: i) Follows trivially by inserting this result back in the equation. Next steps will follow from applying Leibniz rule.

Comment: @mmeent You're absolutely right. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @mmeent I can't reach the rest using Leibniz rule. Would you help me with $\nabla_c \sqrt{-g}=0$? That will get the rest.